Store database configuration in application.properties with spring and Java
I am writing an application that uses several connections to several databases. I created a Map that must contain the connection information. The connections values are stored in the file application.properties.
The file application.properties is stored in the folder /src/main/resources.
The file application.properties contains the following information:
datasource1.database = mydatabase
datasource1.database = mydatabase
datasource1.user = efe
datasource1.password = efe

datasource2.database = security
datasource2.user = scott
datasource2.password = tiger

I tried to use the function ozrg.springframework.core.env.Environment.getPropertyz
to fill in the attributes of a Class that manages this information.
This is my class:
package com.sharex19.sswfe.utils;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PostgresConnector extends DatabaseConnector {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(PostgresConnector.class);
            
    private static PostgresConnector instance=null;
    private static Connection c=null;
    private static HashMap<String,Datasource> cc;
    
    private static String database1;
    private static String user1;
    private static String password1;
    
    private static String database2;
    private static String user2;
    private static String password2;
    
    
    public PostgresConnector() {
        
        System.out.println("CREATION DES COLLECTIONS DE CONNECTIONS");
        
        String database1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.database");
        String user1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.user");
        String password1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.password");
        
        String database2 = env.getProperty("datasource2.database");
        String user2 = env.getProperty("datasource2.user");
        String password2 = env.getProperty("datasource2.password");
        
        
        System.out.println("ACCES A DATABASE1...");
        
        if ( database1 == null ) {
            System.out.println("DATABASE 1 IS NULL");       
        } else {
            System.out.println("DATABASE1:".concat(database1));
        }
        
        System.out.println("DATABASE1:".concat(user1).concat(password1));
        
        System.out.println("ACCES A DATABASE2...");
        
        System.out.println("DATABASE2:".concat(user2).concat(password2));
        
        cc = new HashMap();
        
        cc.put(database1,new Datasource(user1,password1));
        cc.put(database2,new Datasource(user2,password2));
        
    }
    
    public static Connection getInstance(String databasename){
        log.info("APPEL PostgresConnector.getInstance()");
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new PostgresConnector();
            c=PostgresConnector.connect(databasename,
                cc.get(databasename).user,
                cc.get(databasename).password);
        }
        return  c;
    }
    
    public static Connection connect(String databasename, 
        String user, String password) {
        
        System.out.println("database:".concat(databasename));
        System.out.println("user:".concat(user));
        System.out.println("password:".concat(password));
        
          Connection c = null;
          try {
             Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
             c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/".
                concat(databasename),
                    user, password);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
             System.exit(0);
          }
          System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
          return c;
       }
}

I obtain the following information errors:
juil. 17, 2024 9:49:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Le Servlet [SecureSpringWebFlow50] dans l'application web [/SSA19] a retourné une exception lors de son chargement
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String)" because "this.env" is null
    at com.sharex19.sswfe.utils.PostgresConnector.<init>(PostgresConnector.java:52)
    at com.sharex19.sswfe.utils.PostgresConnector$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5f344d4.<init>(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

I tried also to use the annotation @Value(${...}) to do this.

You can even check the sample code provided in the Spring docs which is almost the exact same situation as yours. The only difference is that they don't try to access an autowired variable inside the constructor

if you use the @Autowired as a constructor injection, it should work properly

As you can see

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String)" because "this.env" is null

It clearly says that env is null.
@Autowired loads after the constructor, so if you want to get the property in the constructor, you must pass the Environment as a parameter.
public PostgresConnector(Environment env) {
    ...
}

or create a new function and annotate it with @PostConstruct. Then you can initialise a static field in the function.
@PostConstruct
public init() {
    System.out.println("CREATION DES COLLECTIONS DE CONNECTIONS");
    
    String database1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.database");
    String user1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.user");
    String password1 = env.getProperty("datasource1.password");
    
    ...
}


After adding the parameters Environment Env to the constructor PostgresConnector, it works. The parameters env must be static.
